# gnuplot give wrong results from stats matrix

Tags: matrix, statistics, gnuplot

Suppose that I have the file `data.dat` with follow content:

```
Days          1       2       4       6      10      15      20      30
Group 01    37.80   30.67   62.88   86.06   26.24   98.49   65.42   61.28
Group 02    38.96   72.99   38.24   74.11   39.54   91.59   81.14   91.22
Group 03    82.34   75.25   82.58   28.22   39.21   81.30   41.30   42.48
Group 04    75.52   42.83   66.80   20.50   94.08   74.78   95.09   53.16
Group 05    89.32   56.78   30.05   68.07   59.18   94.18   39.77   67.56
Group 06    70.03   78.71   37.59   60.55   46.40   82.73   67.34   93.38
Group 07    67.83   88.73   48.01   62.19   49.40   67.68   25.97   58.98
Group 08    61.15   96.06   59.62   39.42   60.06   94.18   76.06   32.02
Group 09    65.61   72.39   54.07   92.79   56.58   39.14   81.81   39.16
Group 10    59.65   77.81   40.51   68.49   66.15   80.33   87.31   42.07
```

The final intention is create a histogram using `histogram clustered`.
Besides the graph, I need of some values from `data.dat` such as 
`size_x`, `size_y`, `min`, `max`, and `mean`. To achieve the last task I used

```
set datafile separator tab
stats 'data.dat' skip 1 matrix
```

The summed up output was:

```
* MATRIX: [9 X 10]
  Minimum:            0.0000 [ 0 0 ]
  Maximum:           98.4900 [ 6 0 ]
  Mean:              56.0549
```

The `size_x` and `size_y` values are correct – `9 columns` and `10 rows` – but the `min` is not.
This is due to the fact that the first column is string-type.

When I include `every`

```
set datafile separator tab
stats 'data.dat' skip 1 matrix every ::1
```

to skip the first column, the summed up output is:

```
* MATRIX: [9 X 8] 
  Minimum:           20.5000 [ 0 3 ]
  Maximum:           98.4900 [ 5 0 ]
  Mean:              63.0617
```

This time the `min` and `max` values are right, but the `size_y` (shown `8`, expected `9`) and `index` from `min` (expected `[ 3 3 ]`) is not.

What is going on? I made some mistake? I'm not noticing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got sidetracked trying to characterize the bug revealed by the original answer and forgot to mention a simpler alternative. For this specific case of one row of column headers and one column of rowheaders, gnuplot provides a special syntax that works without error:

```
set file separator tab
stats 'data.dat' matrix rowheaders columnheaders
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I'll wait the bug fix.

Answer (score 2):

The program tries to read a value from the first field of each row, sees "Group xx" and ends up filling in 0 for that entry. You need to tell it to skip the first column.

***Amended answer***

I think there is a bug here, as well as confusion between documentation and the actual implementation.  The matrix rows and columns as implemented by the `every` selector are indexed from 0 to N-1 as they would be for C language arrays.  The documentation incorrectly states or at least implies that the first row and column is matrix[1][1] rather than [0][0]. So the full command needed for your case is

```
gnuplot> set datafile sep tab
gnuplot> stats 'data.dat' every 1:1:1:1 matrix 
         warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values

* FILE: 
  Records:           80
  Out of range:       0
  Invalid:            0
  Header records:     0
  Blank:             10
  Data Blocks:        1

* MATRIX: [9 X 8] 
  Mean:              63.0617
  Std Dev:           20.6729
  Sample StdDev:     20.8033
  Skewness:          -0.1327
  Kurtosis:           1.9515
  Avg Dev:           17.4445
  Sum:             5044.9400
  Sum Sq.:       352332.2181

  Mean Err.:          2.3113
  Std Dev Err.:       1.6343
  Skewness Err.:      0.2739
  Kurtosis Err.:      0.5477

  Minimum:           20.5000 [ 0 3 ]
  Maximum:           98.4900 [ 5 0 ]
```

I.e. `every 1:1:1:1` tells it for both rows and columns the index increment is 1 and the submatrix starts at [1][1] rather than at the origin [0][0].
The output values are all correct, but the indices shown for the size [9 x 8] and the min/max entries are wrong.  I will file a bug report for both issues.

Comment: When I use just `stats 'data.dat' skip 1 every ::2 matrix` (without `set datafile separator tab` before), 
the output is `* MATRIX: [10 X 8]; Minimum: 20.5000 [ 7 2 ]`. 
If I include `set datafile separator tab` the output is `* MATRIX: [9 X 7]; Minimum: 20.5000 [ 5 2 ]`. 
Neither one is right.